# How many event storages should we use by multiple bounded contexts?

Tags: domain-driven-design, event-sourcing, bounded-contexts

I am currently reading about DDD and I did not manage to find answer to this question. If we have a large application with multiple bounded contexts, then as far as I know we should implement each BC as it were a separate application. Thus it is logical to come to the conclusion that each BC has its own UI and event storage. I previously thought that we have only a single event storage because it is the single source of truth according to some articles (about CQRS). The only problem with these statements that they lack of context. So is an event storage the single source of truth in a single bounded context or in the entire application?

Comment: I asked a similar question some time ago on the DDD mail group and sadly didn't get a convincing answer. One of the cons of multiple event stores though would be complicating the replaying of events from all these stores. Would you run them in parallel? in series? How would you queue the incoming events in the meantime? lots of complicated challenges and so little material to guide your decisions :)

Comment: @Songo I have the impression that it is better with multiple storages. At least every bc should be something like a separate application. So replay must be done on bc level and not by every single bc. At least that appears to be logical, but I am not certain either. I'll try to ask somebody with DDD experience, maybe he answers.

Comment: @Songo I talked to the guy, he prefers single event storage and uses multiple event storages only if there is a cause, for example different teams are working on different bc-s, and they don't have access to each other's databases, or it is faster to use multiple event storages, etc. So there is no rule of thumb here, I think I can accept the answer of Dariss.

Comment: Cool! What kind of event store is he using? As far as I know no event store supports this functionality out of the box. I was hoping I could find an event store that supports portioning (i.e. multiple physical stores, but act as a single logical one) much like how you partition a database.

Comment: @Songo Why is that so important? I mean in the current bc you need only the related events. The events of other bc-s act as commands (aka. saga), which can cause different events in your current bc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
  "Is an ES the single source of truth in a bounded context or in entire application?"
```

I guess you meant system, because Bounded Context is an application in the simplest explanation.

```
 "If we have a large application with multiple bounded contexts"
```

You can't have multiple bounded contexts within the same model. Bounded context limits model. So you should change term `bounded context` for `subdomain` and it would be correct.

Anyway answering your question. It depends.

### Single Event Store for whole system

Pros

- One place to manage
- It is easy to see related events by CorrelationID
- In some softwares no need for service discovery. All services (applications) can integrate via single ES (I am talking about true ES not data storage.)
- Less cpu/memory needed

Cons

- Single point of failure (of course you can scale it, to avoid such situation)
- You're coupling services together (breaking microservice's rule)
- Obligated to not change ES during system life time

### One Event Store per application

Pros

- No single point of failure
- Deployed with application
- No coupling between services. More autonomy
- If application will be disabled ES can be disbaled with it
- New services can work with new versions or even a diffrent ES

Cons

- Additional databases to take care about and monitor
- More cpu/ram consumed
- Harder to manage correlationIDs, because they are splitted between multiple ES
- Some service discovery needed. For subscribing to multiple ES or need for extra message queue

Comment: Hmm interesting, I did not realize that you can choose, I thought there is a strict rule.

Comment: Why are you assuming a microservices architecture? Your answer seems to focus on microservices, though the question has nothing to do with it. Or am I misunderstanding your answer?

Comment: We are talking about EventStore within Bounded Context. My answers are based on microservices architecture, you're right here. But how do you apply it: as microservice architecture, SOA architecture or just noname distributed architecture it doesn't matter. If you go with monolith application and you don't concern mulitple ES, because it has no sense.